# Можно ли имея ссылку на интерфейс узнать тип объекта, который спрятан под интерфейсом?

Tags: c#, .net

Можно ли имея ссылку на интерфейс узнать тип объекта, который спрятан под интерфейсом?

Comment: [`GetType()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.object.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx). А зачем это может понадобиться?

Comment: могу предложить две вещи - 1) логгирование (и это ничего страшного) и 2) дополнительная логика (а это уже вызывает подозрения)